# Programmatically get the user's 'Your Files' folder in Palantir Foundry

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories, slate

I need to programmatically retrieve the current user's "Your Files" folder address or resource id in Palantir Foundry. Is it feasible?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Service APIs](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/slate/concepts-queries/#service-apis) in Slate, as stated in the docs, as they might give you some flexibility, but this won't be available out of the box.

Answer (score -1):

the rid of any resource can be seen in the url itself. If you navigate to your home folders the URL looks like this:

https://< domain >/workspace/compass/view/< rid >